# How can I use sound effect in C# console app?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I´m doing this small RPG game in the C# console app, and I wanted to add some background music and effects when choosing menu options.

What I noticed was that I wasn´t able to do anything when the background music started to play. I thought of threading, but this is completly new to me (started to learn C# 6 weeks ago).

What I managed to do was starting a new thread and play the sounds

```
static Thread backgroundMusic = new Thread(() =>
    {

        using (var audioFile = new AudioFileReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\menu.mp3"))
        using (var outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent())
        {
            backgroundMusic.IsBackground = true;
            outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
            outputDevice.Play();
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

        }
    });
```

And then for the sound effect I do...

```
static Thread click = new Thread(() =>
    {

        using (var audioFile = new AudioFileReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\click.mp3"))
        using (var outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent())
        {
            click.IsBackground = true;
            outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
            outputDevice.Play();
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    });
```

I start these with
click.Start();
backgroundMusic.Start();

Ok so far so good. It plays the background music and it plays the sound effect, but only one time. Can I reuse the thread in some way to play the click sound again when another option is chosen?
And can I abort sound in some way? I might want different music when you play the game and in the menus.

tried backgroundMusic.Abort(); but then I got this:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Thread abort is not supported on this platform.'
```

And i can not restart a thread once I´ve started it one time. I tried with
backgroundMusic.Start();

I´ve been checking out forums but all seems to cover windows forms, and not be working with console app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-5.0
I´ve also checked out the documentation... but honestly I think the documentation at microsoft is NOT for beginners. I find it very hard to understand.

I´ve might have been doing it all wrong, so don´t be hard on me, but please come with suggestions how I can improve.

So I want:
Background music playing and looping
Click sound every time you choose a menu option

I have:
Background music playing once (til the end of the file)
Click sound on the first menu option, there after it throws an exception (see above)

Comment: https://markheath.net/post/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. It was a quite advanced solution (from my point of view), we´ll see if all pieces fall together.

Comment: Still having a little problem. Is it possible to stop the background music that I´m playing, to play another song and then start playing the first one again?

Everything else is working now, thanks @RetiredNinja.
Using the implementation in the link at the moment.

Example: Playing intromusic for the game. User starts the game, then I want to change the music. If the user goes back to menu or a store that I´ve implemented, I want to play the menu music again or change  the music to the store music.

Answer (score -1):

You should never, ever use `Thread.Abort()`.  It just stops the thread in an "evil" way - by throwing an exception, and you never know what side effects that will have.

You need `CancellationToken`.  Check out this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads